# How to conjecture a formula of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to conjecture a formula for the $n$th term of $\{a_n\}$ if the first ten terms of the sequence are as follows

1.) $$2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486, 1458, 4374, 13122, 39366$$

2.) $$1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1$$

I have no idea how to even start to come up with a formula.  Do I need to use induction here?

Comment: It often helps to consider the difference and the quotient of successive terms. Try this for the first problem. For the second one, there seems to be a rather obvious pattern, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, we have $a_0 = 2,$ and for $n\in \mathbb Z, n\geq 1,\quad a_n = 3a_{n-1}$

Alternatively, note that $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = 3$.

For the second, if we start with $n=1$, so $a_1 = 1$, then for $n\geq 1$ define $$a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & n\not\equiv 0 \pmod 3\\ 0& n \equiv 0 \pmod 3\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when confronted with a sequence, the simplest way to conjecture some closed forms is to use the *method of differences*.

This is based on the observation that if $a_n = \alpha n^k + \alpha'n^{k'} + \dots$ then we can quickly find the degree $k$ of that polynomial by repeatedly computing differences between successive terms until they're all equal.

Take, for example, take the sequence $-3, -2, 1, 6, 13, 22, 33, \dots$. Computing the differences:
$$\begin{matrix}
-3 & & -2 & & 1 & & 6 & & 13 & & 22 & & 33 \\
 & 1 & & 3 & & 5 & & 7 & & 9 & & 11 & \\
 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & & \\
\end{matrix}$$

After $2$ computations the differences are all equal: that means the sequence can be expressed as a polynomial in the form $\alpha n^2 + \beta n + \gamma$. One usually starts from $n^2$ and adjusts accordingly. After some experimentation, you quickly find that in this case $a_n = n^2 - 3$.

Coming to your problems, if you apply this method to your $(1)$ you notice something strange: the method of differences never terminates! After a while you get stuck in a loop and the differences are always the same. This tells us an important bit of information: the sequence cannot be expressed as a *polynomial*. The simplest thing to try is something exponential. You can also come up with a recursive formula, as @amWhy did, and work from there. From $a_0 = 2, a_n = 3a_{n-1}$ it is obvious then that $a_n = 2 \cdot 3^n$.

For the second one, those repeating digits suggest that $(2)$ has something to do with modulus. In fact, after some experimentation, you can easily come up with something like: $a_n = n^2 \mod 3$.

Comment: For your first example, you can read off the formula from the leftmost column of the difference table: $$-3\binom{n}{0}+1\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}=-3+n+n(n-1)=n^2-3$$

Comment: @RobPratt Great input!